# Avoid google crawl or index font text in ligatures to show in sitelinks

Tags: html, fonts, materialize, ligature

I'm using materialize Css framework in my proyect. It use a icon-font to achieve render icons like a font by ligature as that:

```
<i class="material-icons">add</i>
```

This are render in browser as : +
The problem is that i have some links in my web with the following code:

```
<a href="/example"><i class="material-icons> add </i> Example </a>
```

and google show in his sitelinks as literal "addExample". waf!!

How could i solve? Thanks.

Note: Sitelinks are the diferent sub-sections in google results searching form a web. Here's an example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04KW5.jpg)

Comment: Take the <i> out of the link text and place it before or after the link

Comment: @Chris it's not the ideal solution, as one may want to have both text along with icon to be linked to target.

Comment: Then the only option I can see (yes i know im many months late to respond but I suppose its less than years ;) ) is to leave <i> empty so just create it without inner html. presuming you don't also need that text for something else. This will remove the add and keep the image if it doesnt work just add a non breaking space as the inner html.

Comment: I can't do that. Material icons uses as known like ligature. I need the text "add" inside <i> tag. In other way it don´t work